# Is there a TryInt() conversion for String values?

Tags: c#, winforms, type-conversion

I want to convert a value entered in a textBox (which can only be empty or "1" or "2" or "3") to an integer. If empty I want it to be 0, otherwise, it's corresponding value (1, 2, or 3).

Is there a way to do that like:

```
MyIntVal = TryConvertToInt(textBox1.Text, 0);
```

...where an empty string or anything not readily convertible to an int would default to 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int result = 0;
int.TryParse(stringValue, out result);
```

Will default to 0 if stringValue cannot be parsed to an int.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Comment: Just an FYI, it's unnecessary (even pointless) to assign the initial 0 value to 'result'.  See dtb's answer below.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [Int32.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx):

```
int myIntVal;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out myIntVal))
{
    myIntVal = 42;
}
```

If the method returns `false`, the text could not be parsed. `myIntVal` will be `0` in this case; you can assign a different default value to your variable as shown above.

Answer (score 7):

There's the static `TryParse`. It returns `true` if it works.

```
int myIntVal;
int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out myIntVal);
```